# Python dictionary insertion and deletion

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print("Before deleting:\n") 

od = {}

od['a'] = 1

od['b'] = 2

od['c'] = 3

od['d'] = 4

for key, value in od.items(): 

    print(key, value) 

print("\nAfter deleting:\n") 

od.pop('c') 

for key, value in od.items(): 

    print(key, value) 

print("\nAfter re-inserting:\n") 

od['c'] = 3

for key, value in od.items(): 

      print(key, value)
```

After running this I am getting

Before deleting:

```
('a', 1)
('c', 3)
('b', 2)
('d', 4)
```

After deleting:

```
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('d', 4)
```

After re-inserting:

```
('a', 1)
('c', 3)
('b', 2)
('d', 4)
```

My question why `c` is inserting at second place and for the record whatever may be the value of `c` it is always inserted in second place.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What minor version of Python are you running? It shouldn't behave like that in 3.6+ (with insertion ordered `dict`s), but earlier versions are "hash ordered, but with jumping around on collisions", which is effectively equivalent to "no useful order to speak of".

Comment: I was just using the editor in Geeksforgeeks. Thanks for the help

Comment: In the generic editions of the python interpreters, c always gets appended at the end after d

Comment: @SauravSaha: No, it doesn't. That's a new feature in 3.6 (3.7 is when it's first guaranteed by the language standard). A 3.5 or earlier interpreter would not have that behavior.

Comment: dictionary in python is un-ordered , it is just random

Comment: @SarthakGupta: Nope again. In CPython 3.6+, they're insertion-ordered (and any Python 3.7+ *must* provide insertion-ordered `dict`s). Does no one read the prior comments at all?

Comment: @ShadowRanger, oh yes I tested it out in Python 3.5, and yes it is pretty weird, is is not insertion ordered as you mentioned. In my case the key value pair of c is being attached in the order between b and d, and my final dictionary looks something like this - {'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger, got to know about something new and very unexpected!

Comment: @SauravSaha: Yes, there is a per-run hash seed for string/bytes-like things that perturbs their hash (to defend against denial of service attacks from a malicious user submitting entries chosen to have colliding hashes), so before insertion-ordering was a thing, after the hash seed was turned on by default in 3.3 (and even now, for `set`s), the ordering of `str` (and `bytes` and `datetime` and anything else which defers to their hashes in some way) will differ from run to run, even on the same interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually on Python 2, not Python 3, as evidenced by the output of your `print`s; `print` is a statement on Python 2 (barring your code including `from __future__ import print_function` at the top), not a function call (like it is on Py3, or on Py2 with the `__future__` import), so the parentheses just made a `tuple`, which you printed.

Prior to Python 3.6, `dict`s have no useful ordering (it's tied to the hash of the keys, but collision resolution means the ordering can change simply because the `dict` was constructed in a different order), but reinserting a given key will *often* (not guaranteed) put it in the same bucket, keeping it in the same iteration position.

If you're looking for insertion ordered behavior (you want `'c'` to move to the end), either upgrade to Python 3.6+ (3.7+ required to have it guaranteed, but all existing 3.6 interpreters have it as an implementation detail), or using `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: If I want to insert c in the 3rd position then how can I do that

Comment: @A_the_kunal: You can't. Or more precisely, you can't do it pre-3.6 at all without `OrderedDict`. If you use a 3.6+ `dict` or `OrderedDict`, it would have been constructed with `'c'` in the 3rd position from the start (removing it and readding it would move it to the end). If it's in the wrong order, and you can't change how it was created, you're stuck with lots of manual popping and reinsertion, or more simply, you just get `list(mydict.items())`, reorder the `list` however you want, then convert back with the `dict`/`OrderedDict` constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Note that dictionaries in python are unordered - since the values in the dictionary are indexed by keys, they are not held in any particular order.

Comment: So everytime when generating output I should get different order right, but this is a pre defined order

Comment: They're insertion ordered in 3.6+. The OP is using Python 2 (as evidenced by their `print` output being `tuple`s).

Answer (score -1):

**Python dictionaries are implemented using hash tables**. It is an array whose indexes are obtained using a hash function on the keys.

For any given key(lets say it is a string) it first passes through a hash function and then mask it with (arr_size -1). The entire:  ***hash_func('a') & (arr_size -1)*** gives the index of key-value pair in the array.

(k, v) -------------> index(n=8)    (k, v)

(a, 1) ----h('a')&7-->   0          (a, 1)

(b, 2) ----h('b')&7-->   1          (b, 2)

(c, 1) ----h('c')&7-->   2          (c, 3)

This is why the index of key 'c' is not changing.

[src](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/)

Comment: They're insertion ordered in 3.6+. The OP is using Python 2 (as evidenced by their `print` output being `tuple`s).

Answer (score -1):

Starting from Python 3.7, insertion order of Python dictionaries is guaranteed

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... They're *not* getting insertion ordering.